# ASP WebAPI generic List optional parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm really struggling with this one. I need a generic list parameter for my Get method, but it needs to be optional. I just did this:

```
public dynamic Get(List <long> ManufacturerIDs = null)
```

Unfortunately on runtime i get the error:

> Optional parameter 'ManufacturerIDs' is not supported by
>   'FormatterParameterBinding'.

How to get a generic list as an optional parameter here?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

What's the point of using an optional parameter? `List<T>` is a reference type and if the client doesn't supply a value it will simply be null:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(List<long> manufacturerIDs)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: In my experience, there are many cases where you have to explicitly set optional parameters to null (http://stackoverflow.com/a/22397723/1454888). This is counter-intuitive for me, but it works. Thanks.

Comment: I am using swashbuckle for swagger documentation generation. In that context it does matter how the optional parameters are defined, observe: 
`[FromUri] object[] foo = null` --> "Provide multiple values in new lines."
`[FromUri] object[] foo` --> "Provide multiple values in new lines (at least one required)."
`object[] foo` --> "(required)" 
So in that context it really depends on what you expect from your end user.

Comment: I had to insert [FromUri] attribute before the List<string> optional parameter. There is a difference when you use = null as @Nebula noticed. When you don't add = null then you have to specify at least one element.