# web api method cant found from web application

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

here is the startup ruinning controller method in web application:

```
public ActionResult PaginationOfBooks(string _title, string _author, string _description, string _publisher)
        {

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:57752");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/Book/GetBooks").Result;
```

rest is not important yet. Actually at this point, in debug mode I expect to switch WebApi project that in same solution with Web app, GetBooks method I have break point at first line of this method.. here is the content of result:

```
StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
```

my web abi project:

```
public ActionResult GetBooks(string _title, string _author, string _description, string _publisher)
        {
            var draw = 1;
...
```

webapi config:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/Book/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));
        }
    }
```

how can I get this web api request?

I run api project and simply tried to access method with this:
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Attribute routing with optional parameters in ASP.NET Web API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22388452/attribute-routing-with-optional-parameters-in-asp-net-web-api)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a route attribute before the api method

```
[Route("api/Book/GetBooks/{_title}/{_author}/{_description}/{_publisher}")]
public ActionResult GetBooks(string _title, string _author, string _description, string _publisher)
        {
            var draw = 1;
...
```

then call it as

```
public ActionResult PaginationOfBooks(string _title, string _author, string _description, string _publisher)
        {

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:57752");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/Book/GetBooks/" + _title + "/" + _author + "/" + _description + "/" + _publisher).Result;
```

Comment: its for GET not for POST, you used get so I show get

Comment: yes I am able to access api method with "localhost:57752/api/Book/GetBooks/title..." from browser but I need access it within application

Comment: I have show you how to access it using `HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/Book/GetBooks/" + _title + "/" + _author + "/" + _description + "/" + _publisher).Result;` , do you need more detail ?

Comment: No I am ok with it now its working :) but how can I a step into web api method in debugging, I simply press f11 in "client.GetAsync(..)" method and expected to switch the breakpoint in api method..  what should I do for debugging api ?

Comment: because its async method so you have to await it then you can set a breakpoint on it, try to apply async await approach

Comment: How can I convert this request to await, is it easy or some extra work ?

Answer (score 1):

Change your WebApiConfig like this-

```
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "BooksApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{email}/{firstname}/{lastname}/{source}"
    );
```

And call from PaginationOfBooks like this-

```
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/Book/GetBooks/" + _title + "/" + _author + "/" + _description + "/" + _publisher).Result;
```

See if this helps.