# Optional parameter using Route attribute in web API?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I want two patterns of API url point to the same API action method:

```
api/Cities/{countryCode}
```

and

```
api/Cities
```

Is this possible to configure using `Route` attribute?

I made this and didn't work:

```
   [HttpGet, Route("GetCities/{code?}")]
        public dynamic GetCities(string code)
        {
            return GENOrderRepository.SelectCities(Context, code);
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Attribute routing with optional parameters in ASP.NET Web API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22388452/attribute-routing-with-optional-parameters-in-asp-net-web-api)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just create one action method, and use the route attribute like this:

```
Route[("api/Cities/{countryCode?}")]
```

(Note the question mark at the end, that makes a parameter optional). You also have to supply a default parameter to the parameter. See my working sample:

```
 [HttpGet, Route("GetCities/{code?}")]
 public IHttpActionResult GetCities(string code=null)
 {
     return Ok();
 }
```

Comment: Please see the amended question

Comment: Thanks for the sample. This shows that you have left out the default parameter from the action method. Please check my edit in the answer.

Comment: I see it used like: `num:int?` what is this?

Comment: That specifies the url parameter `num` as an optional integer (`:int` for the integer and `?` for the optional). By default url parameters are __usually__ treated as strings.